# Linked in API for campaign creation creates legacy campaigns

Tags: linkedin-api

Referring to the api docs for linked in campaign management:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-campaigns?tabs=http#create-a-campaign

Following the same when campaign is created it is created as a legacy campaign.

How to create a normal campaign via the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passing

```
    "objectiveType": "BRAND_AWARENESS",
```

this entry in json body worked.